# Prevent angular from interpolation {{}} before angular.bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a variable exposed on rootScope e.g.:

```
$rootScope.hey = 'hey';
```

and I want it displayed on index.html as `{{hey}}`. However angular replaces this with and empty value before angular.bootstrap is called (which is done after requirejs has loaded all the files).

How can I get it to stay as `{{hey}}` till angular.bootstrap is called.

***Note:*** ng-bind would be one solution e.g. `<div ng-bind="hey"></div>` but for my particular case I need to pass the value via interpolation.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. An `ng-app` attribute had snuck up in index.html. Removed it.